# Can anybody help me debug my error

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a website with HTML and JavaScript. When I run my code it does run however my if else statement never hits the else case no matter what is typed in. could someone tell me what is wrong. I'm new with Forms and javaScript but I assume most things with JavaScript are the same as Java. Anyway, code below.

```
    <form id="eForm">        
    <script>

    function CheckForm()
    {
    var first=document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
    var mid=document.getElementsByTagName("input")[1].value;
    var last=document.getElementsByTagName("input")[2].value;
    var email=document.getElementsByTagName("input")[3].value;
    var date=document.getElementsByTagName("input")[4].value;
    var time=document.getElementsByTagName("input")[5].value;


    if((document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value !=="first" || document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value !=="") && 

    (document.getElementsByTagName("input")[1].value !=="Initial" || document.getElementsByTagName("input")[1].value !=="") && 

    (document.getElementsByTagName("input")[2].value !=="last" || document.getElementsByTagName("input")[2].value !=="") && 

    (document.getElementsByTagName("input")[3].value !=="someone@example.com" || document.getElementsByTagName("input")[3].value !=="") && 

    (document.getElementsByTagName("input")[4].value !=="xx/xx/xxxx" || document.getElementsByTagName("input")[4].value !=="") && 

    (document.getElementsByTagName("input")[5].value !=="xx:xx" || document.getElementsByTagName("input")[5].value !==""))
    {
    document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value='fail';
    }
    else
    {
    alert("One or more fields were not filled in correctly. /n Please try again.");
    document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value='works';
    }

    first.value='works';
    }
    </script>

    First name: <input type="text" name="FirstName" id="FirstName" value="first"><br>
    Middle Initial: <input type="text" name="MidName" id="MidName" value="Initial"><br>
    Last name: <input type="text" name="LastName" id="LastName" value="last"><br>
    E-Mail: <input type="text" name="Email" id="Email" value="someone@example.com"><br>
    Date for request: <input type="date" name="Date" id="Date" value="xx/xx/xxxx"><br>
    Time for request: <input type="time" name="Time" id="Time" value="xx:xx"> 
    AM<input type="radio" name="AM/PM" id="AM" checked="true">
    PM<input type="radio" name="AM/PM" id="PM" checked="false"><br>

    <input onclick="CheckForm()" type="button" value="Submit">
    <input onclick="CheckForm()" type="submit" value="Submit">

    On Submit, if a feild is left not filled out, then do not go through and show a message saying that "One or more feilds are not filled out. You must fill them 

    out in order to submit this form."

    </form>
```

In hindsight(still 20/20) I should have realized that the expression was alway true do to my or statements so thank you v2b for pointing that out.

Comment: Have your tried using the developer tools (f12) in your browser of choice? Usually it will give you error messages and break on the offending lines of code.

Comment: Note i have spent hours trying to debug this myself and researching, I'm not trying to just shortcut things by asking others for knowledge and if I find the answer on my own I will post in case others end up with the same issue as mine.

Comment: yes, i have tried that it doesn't give me any errors, only thing i could guess is that it is a logic error

Comment: Man, I can't see the property "name" in tag <form>. If you can do a submit, it's necessary.

Comment: You really need to learn how to use functions and call them, use some sort of for loop etc. This is just a bad way to write code.

Comment: @ViniciusLima: No, it really isn't.

Comment: "...assume most things with JavaScript are the same as Java" JavaScript is actually a name for ECMAScript, chosen to SOUND like it was something that it is not! A lot of people have been thrown off by this intentional misdirection. Like Nulcear said: JS!=Java.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the Javascript code? The developer tools in any modern browser will let you do that. You can examine your variables and see what is failing. Are you seeing 'fail' appear in the first input? If not, you are getting an exception somewhere. Are you sure that exceptions are being reported in the developer tools? Sometimes you have to enable that. What browser are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value !=="first" || document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value !=="")

will always evaluate to be true.. remember it's a OR, even if one is true it's a true.. 
if the value is "first" then it will be (false || true), 
if it is "xyz" then it will be (true || true), 
if is it "" then it will be (true || false)

and similarly the other 5 lines too..

EDIT:
the following will do what you want it to do. Also, do not repeat document.getElementsByTagName too many times. Dom access it expensive. In your case, there is no need to repeat it again and again. You can do it as follows,

```
var inputElement = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

if((inputElement[0].value !=="first" && inputElement[0].value !=="") && 
    (inputElement[1].value !=="Initial" && inputElement[1].value !=="") && 
    (inputElement[2].value !=="last" && inputElement[2].value !=="") && 
    (inputElement[3].value !=="someone@example.com" && inputElement[3].value !=="") && 
    (inputElement[4].value !=="xx/xx/xxxx" && inputElement[4].value !=="") && 
    (inputElement[5].value !=="xx:xx" && inputElement[5].value !==""))
{
    inputElement[0].value='fail';
}
else
{
    alert("One or more fields were not filled in correctly. /n Please try again.");
    inputElement[0].value='works';
}
```

Comment: *FacePalm* ok I feel stupid. I knew it was something stupid like that. Thank you. Also, thanks for the info on Dom access.

Answer (score 3):

I am not (and no one is, really) going to debug your code for you. But here are some points to get you going:

- **Your script runs before the inputs are even loaded. Place the `<script>` element at the bottom of the page, just below the closing `</body>`.**
- Your inputs have names, use them:

  ```
  var form = document.forms[0]; //Or getElementByID, whatever
  console.log(form["FirstName"]); //The first name input.
  ```
- Your condition is much too long. Check for items separately and return an appropriate error each time. You'll be doing your users a favor too!
- You aren't using `<label>`s to mark your input labels. Do that.
- Use `<input placeholder="placeholder">` to have placeholder text. (And not just give an initial value). Also, since you have labels, placeholder text is redundant.

Comment: @Alohci: How are these not correct? And how are these not relevant? The first point hits the spot. The script gets run before the inputs even exist. The rest are optional but still important to have.

Comment: Two examples. The script runs early, but only creates a function. The function runs when the buttons are clicked. Placeholders and labels are not redundant. The [HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html#the-placeholder-attribute) specifically says: "The placeholder attribute should not be used as a replacement for a label."

Comment: @Alohci: But since the label exists, the placeholder *is* redundant. The placeholder shouldn't stand alone, but is redundant when used with a label. Also, you are correct about the first point.